# find lists with the same value on index [1] in list

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

i have a list in list and want to find all lists with the same value on index[1]. The lists in list have always the same len.

list = [['10302', '118073', 'So, 07.02.2021', '302'], ['10301', '118074', 'So, 07.02.2021', '301'], ['10032', '118075', 'So, 07.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118076', 'So, 07.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118077', 'So, 07.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118078', 'So, 07.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118079', 'So, 07.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118080', 'So, 07.02.2021', '32'], ['10411', '118081', 'So, 07.02.2021', '411'], ['10402', '118082', 'So, 07.02.2021', '402'], ['10302', '118083', 'So, 14.02.2021', '302'], ['10301', '118084', 'So, 14.02.2021', '301'], ['10032', '118085', 'So, 14.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118086', 'So, 14.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118087', 'So, 14.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118088', 'So, 14.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118089', 'So, 14.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118090', 'So, 14.02.2021', '32'], ['10034', '118091', 'So, 14.02.2021', '34'], ['10411', '118092', 'So, 14.02.2021', '411'], ['10411', '118092', 'So, 21.02.2021', '411'], ['10402', '118093', 'So, 14.02.2021', '402'], ['10005', '118095', 'Mo, 15.02.2021', '5'], ['10314', '118096', 'Mo, 15.02.2021', '314'], ['10313', '118097', 'Mo, 15.02.2021', '313'], ['10312', '118098', 'Mo, 15.02.2021', '312'], ['10035', '118099', 'Mo, 15.02.2021', '35'], ['10030', '118100', 'Mo, 15.02.2021', '30'], ['10302', '118101', 'So, 21.02.2021', '302'], ['10301', '118102', 'So, 21.02.2021', '301'], ['10411', '118103', 'So, 21.02.2021', '411'], ['10402', '118104', 'So, 21.02.2021', '402'], ['10214', '118105', 'So, 28.02.2021', '214'], ['10005', '118106', 'So, 28.02.2021', '5'], ['10314', '118107', 'So, 28.02.2021', '314'], ['10313', '118108', 'So, 28.02.2021', '313'], ['10312', '118109', 'So, 28.02.2021', '312'], ['10302', '118110', 'So, 28.02.2021', '302'], ['10301', '118111', 'So, 28.02.2021', '301'], ['10311', '118112', 'So, 28.02.2021', '311'], ['10035', '118113', 'So, 28.02.2021', '35'], ['10030', '118114', 'So, 28.02.2021', '30'], ['10032', '118115', 'So, 28.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118116', 'So, 28.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118117', 'So, 28.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118118', 'So, 28.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118119', 'So, 28.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118120', 'So, 28.02.2021', '32'], ['10358', '118121', 'So, 28.02.2021', '358'], ['10350', '118122', 'So, 28.02.2021', '350'], ['10352', '118123', 'So, 28.02.2021', '352'], ['10359', '118124', 'So, 28.02.2021', '359'], ['10412', '118125', 'So, 28.02.2021', '412'], ['10411', '118126', 'So, 28.02.2021', '411'], ['10408', '118127', 'So, 28.02.2021', '408'], ['10402', '118128', 'So, 28.02.2021', '402'], ['10801', '118129', 'So, 28.02.2021', '801'], ['10818', '118130', 'So, 28.02.2021', '818'], ['10817', '118131', 'So, 28.02.2021', '817']]

result = [['10411', **'118092'**, 'So, 14.02.2021', '411'], ['10411', **'118092'**, 'So, 21.02.2021', '411']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiom I like to use for this type of grouping problem is to use a `dict` of `lists`, where the key is the relevant element of the list, and the value is the list itself. In this case, our key is `lst[1]` for each element.

```
bigList = [['10302', '118073', 'So, 07.02.2021', '302'], ['10301', '118074', 'So, 07.02.2021', '301'], ['10032', '118075', 'So, 07.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118076', 'So, 07.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118077', 'So, 07.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118078', 'So, 07.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118079', 'So, 07.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118080', 'So, 07.02.2021', '32'], ['10411', '118081', 'So, 07.02.2021', '411'], ['10402', '118082', 'So, 07.02.2021', '402'], ['10302', '118083', 'So, 14.02.2021', '302'], ['10301', '118084', 'So, 14.02.2021', '301'], ['10032', '118085', 'So, 14.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118086', 'So, 14.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118087', 'So, 14.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118088', 'So, 14.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118089', 'So, 14.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118090', 'So, 14.02.2021', '32'], ['10034', '118091', 'So, 14.02.2021', '34'], ['10411', '118092', 'So, 14.02.2021', '411'], ['10411', '118092', 'So, 21.02.2021', '411'], ['10402', '118093', 'So, 14.02.2021', '402'], ['10005', '118095', 'Mo, 15.02.2021', '5'], ['10314', '118096', 'Mo, 15.02.2021', '314'], ['10313', '118097', 'Mo, 15.02.2021', '313'], ['10312', '118098', 'Mo, 15.02.2021', '312'], ['10035', '118099', 'Mo, 15.02.2021', '35'], ['10030', '118100', 'Mo, 15.02.2021', '30'], ['10302', '118101', 'So, 21.02.2021', '302'], ['10301', '118102', 'So, 21.02.2021', '301'], ['10411', '118103', 'So, 21.02.2021', '411'], ['10402', '118104', 'So, 21.02.2021', '402'], ['10214', '118105', 'So, 28.02.2021', '214'], ['10005', '118106', 'So, 28.02.2021', '5'], ['10314', '118107', 'So, 28.02.2021', '314'], ['10313', '118108', 'So, 28.02.2021', '313'], ['10312', '118109', 'So, 28.02.2021', '312'], ['10302', '118110', 'So, 28.02.2021', '302'], ['10301', '118111', 'So, 28.02.2021', '301'], ['10311', '118112', 'So, 28.02.2021', '311'], ['10035', '118113', 'So, 28.02.2021', '35'], ['10030', '118114', 'So, 28.02.2021', '30'], ['10032', '118115', 'So, 28.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118116', 'So, 28.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118117', 'So, 28.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118118', 'So, 28.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118119', 'So, 28.02.2021', '32'], ['10032', '118120', 'So, 28.02.2021', '32'], ['10358', '118121', 'So, 28.02.2021', '358'], ['10350', '118122', 'So, 28.02.2021', '350'], ['10352', '118123', 'So, 28.02.2021', '352'], ['10359', '118124', 'So, 28.02.2021', '359'], ['10412', '118125', 'So, 28.02.2021', '412'], ['10411', '118126', 'So, 28.02.2021', '411'], ['10408', '118127', 'So, 28.02.2021', '408'], ['10402', '118128', 'So, 28.02.2021', '402'], ['10801', '118129', 'So, 28.02.2021', '801'], ['10818', '118130', 'So, 28.02.2021', '818'], ['10817', '118131', 'So, 28.02.2021', '817']]

lists = {}
for lst in bigList:
    lists.setdefault(lst[1], [])
    lists[lst[1]].append(lst)

result = lists['118092']
# [['10411', '118092', 'So, 14.02.2021', '411'], ['10411', '118092', 'So, 21.02.2021', '411']]
```

Once we've sorted the big list into a dict of lists-of-lists-sharing-their-second-element, we can pick out a specific lists-with-second-element (e.g. `lists['118092']` for all the lists with that at their index 1), or get a triply-nested list grouped by the values at index 1, via `list(lists.values())`.

Comment: Sorry! The result '118092' is not known.

Comment: I have to search through all lists in the list for possibly identical values ​​in index [1] and then return the lists found.
Many Thanks!

Comment: `[key for key, value in lists.items() if len(value)>1]`